# Start and end times within time intervals

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have performance data that includes machine id, task, speed, and process. I need to know duration of speed and process within 24-hour intervals (0700-0700)

| id | task | speed | process | recorded_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Updating | 35 | Started | 1/1/24 09:00 |
| 1 | Updating | 0 | Paused | 1/1/24 10:30 |
| 1 | Updating | 15 | Restarted | 1/1/24 11:00 |
| 1 | Updating | 15 | Speed Verify | 1/1/24 12:00 |
| 1 | Updating | 0 | Complete | 1/1/24 16:00 |
| 1 | Syncing | 10 | Started | 1/1/24 19:00 |

I want to group the data to show start and end time of one speed and process to the next, as well as the final end time to be the end of the 24 hour interval if there are no further entries.
Expected output:

| id | task | speed | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Updating | 35 | 1/1/24 09:00 | 1/1/24 10:30 |
| 1 | Updating | 0 | 1/1/24 10:30 | 1/1/24 11:00 |
| 1 | Updating | 15 | 1/1/24 11:00 | 1/1/24 16:00 |
| 1 | Syncing | 10 | 1/1/24 19:00 | 1/2/24 07:00 |

I am thinking that I will need to use the lead function to find the next start time based on change in speed.
For the last stop time, I tried using max(id) to find the last row and case when rate does not equal zero in order to select the end interval time, but I am not sure this is the right approach.

Thank you!

Comment: You probably need to use some combination of `lead()` or `lag()` and maybe a `last_value()`.  I can help create a query for you, but I don't know how you're getting the end_time for the last record, and why are you skipping some of the values like `Speed Verify`?

Comment: you most liky want to use Conditional change event https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event to mark the edges of batch, at which point in a another layer of select to can then find the first last, for the batch you have identified. Or manually do the logic of conditional_change_event and still need another layer.

Comment: @MikeWalton good questions. The start and end interval come from the start and end of each 24 hour interval-in the above example it would be a start_interval of 1/1/24 0700 and end_interval of 1/2/24 0700. I am ignoring the values of speed verify if the speed has not changed. Ultimately, I am trying to find duration of recorded speeds by task in each 24 hour period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so assuming you want batches of ID with speed greeter than zero, you can use CONDITIONAL_EVENT_CHANGE

```
with data(id, task, speed, process, recorded_time) as (
    select $1,$2,$3,$4, to_timestamp_ntz($5, 'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI') from values
    (1, 'Updating', 35  ,'Started', '1/1/24 09:00'),
    (1, 'Updating', 0   ,'Paused',  '1/1/24 10:30'),
    (1, 'Updating', 15  ,'Restarted',   '1/1/24 11:00'),
    (1, 'Updating', 15  ,'Speed Verify',    '1/1/24 12:00'),
    (1, 'Updating', 0   ,'Complete',    '1/1/24 16:00'),
    (1, 'Syncing', 10   ,'Started', '1/1/24 19:00')
)
select
    D.*
    ,CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(d.speed>0) over (partition by d.id order by d.recorded_time) as batch
from data as d;
```

| ID | TASK | SPEED | PROCESS | RECORDED_TIME | BATCH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Updating | 35 | Started | 2024-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 1 | Updating | 0 | Paused | 2024-01-01 10:30:00.000 | 1 |
| 1 | Updating | 15 | Restarted | 2024-01-01 11:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 1 | Updating | 15 | Speed Verify | 2024-01-01 12:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 1 | Updating | 0 | Complete | 2024-01-01 16:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 1 | Syncing | 10 | Started | 2024-01-01 19:00:00.000 | 4 |

now you can min those batches to get the start event.

skipping some steps:

```
with data(id, task, speed, process, recorded_time) as (
    select $1,$2,$3,$4, to_timestamp_ntz($5, 'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI') from values
    (1, 'Updating', 35  ,'Started', '1/1/24 09:00'),
    (1, 'Updating', 0   ,'Paused',  '1/1/24 10:30'),
    (1, 'Updating', 15  ,'Restarted',   '1/1/24 11:00'),
    (1, 'Updating', 15  ,'Speed Verify',    '1/1/24 12:00'),
    (1, 'Updating', 0   ,'Complete',    '1/1/24 16:00'),
    (1, 'Syncing', 10   ,'Started', '1/1/24 19:00'),
    (2, 'Syncing', 10   ,'Started', '1/1/24 4:00')
), step_one as (
    select
        D.*
        ,CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(d.speed>0) over (partition by d.id order by d.recorded_time) as batch
    from data as d
), step_two as (
    select
        s1.*
        ,iff(min(recorded_time)over(partition by id,batch) = recorded_time, recorded_time, null) as batch_start 
    from step_one as s1
)
select s2.*
    ,lead(batch_start) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by recorded_time) as lead_batch_end
    ,dateadd('hours', 7, date_trunc('day', dateadd('hours',24-7,recorded_time))) as end_trunc
    ,nvl(lead_batch_end, end_trunc) as batch_end
from step_two as s2
order by id, recorded_time;
```

[image]

The reason for keeping the data like this (where it's dropped next), is so deeper logic, or sums, and splitting across day breaks can be done. It all really depends how you are weaving the story, but this should give a highly directional point in one of the right directions

which becomes:

```
with data(id, task, speed, process, recorded_time) as (
    select $1,$2,$3,$4, to_timestamp_ntz($5, 'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI') from values
    (1, 'Updating', 35  ,'Started', '1/1/24 09:00'),
    (1, 'Updating', 0   ,'Paused',  '1/1/24 10:30'),
    (1, 'Updating', 15  ,'Restarted',   '1/1/24 11:00'),
    (1, 'Updating', 15  ,'Speed Verify',    '1/1/24 12:00'),
    (1, 'Updating', 0   ,'Complete',    '1/1/24 16:00'),
    (1, 'Syncing', 10   ,'Started', '1/1/24 19:00'),
    (2, 'Syncing', 10   ,'Started', '1/1/24 4:00')
), step_one as (
    select
        D.*
        ,CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(d.speed>0) over (partition by d.id order by d.recorded_time) as batch
    from data as d
), step_two as (
    select
        s1.*
        ,iff(min(recorded_time)over(partition by id,batch) = recorded_time, recorded_time, null) as batch_start 
    from step_one as s1
)
select s2.* exclude(process,batch, batch_start) rename(recorded_time as start_time)
    ,nvl(
        lead(batch_start) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by recorded_time)
        , dateadd('hours', 7, date_trunc('day', dateadd('hours',24-7,recorded_time)))) as batch_end
from step_two as s2
where batch_start is not null
order by id, recorded_time;
```

| ID | TASK | SPEED | START_TIME | BATCH_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Updating | 35 | 2024-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 2024-01-01 10:30:00.000 |
| 1 | Updating | 0 | 2024-01-01 10:30:00.000 | 2024-01-01 11:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Updating | 15 | 2024-01-01 11:00:00.000 | 2024-01-01 16:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Updating | 0 | 2024-01-01 16:00:00.000 | 2024-01-01 19:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Syncing | 10 | 2024-01-01 19:00:00.000 | 2024-01-02 07:00:00.000 |
| 2 | Syncing | 10 | 2024-01-01 04:00:00.000 | 2024-01-01 07:00:00.000 |

Comment: Thank you for building this query! I really appreciate your help Simeon